# how to add validation rule to an email field in jsf page?

Tags: oracle-adf

ADF Client side validation – Email validation:

I want to add a validation rule to an email field so it doesnt accept invalid emails when entered (but remains not required, so its either empty or valid).

I used a Validate Regular Expression on the Email field in the jsf page with these arguments:

Pattern: ^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$
Message: You have entered an invalid email address. Please try again.

The problems are:

1- When entering an invalid email, it works but when entering a valid email the error message still appears.

2- The email field becomes mandatory even though its not.

Comment: Does it work when entering directly a good email? If yes, try playing with the Immediate / AutoTab and clientComponent attributes

Comment: Also try modifying the RegExp to accept empty value